# TypeError: $.url is not a function

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I am having a javascript file named _report_js.html.erb file under app/views/reports. WHen I run my application, I am getting the error:

> TypeError: $.url is not a function

This is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if($.url().param('ig') == 'true') {
      alert("hi");
      $('#icons').hide();
      $('#photos').show();
    end
</script>
```

Comment: which library is it?

Comment: Do you have such  plugin included in page? `$.url` is not a jQuery core method

Answer (score 5):

```
$.url()
```

is not part of the jQuery Core. If you want to achieve something similiar, maybe use

```
var getUrlParameter = function getUrlParameter(sParam) {
    var sPageURL = decodeURIComponent(window.location.search.substring(1)),
        sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&'),
        sParameterName,
        i;

    for (i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) {
        sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');

        if (sParameterName[0] === sParam) {
            return sParameterName[1] === undefined ? true : sParameterName[1];
        }
    }
};
```

to use it:

```
var tech = getUrlParameter('technology');
```

In your example it would something like this

```
if(getUrlParameter('ig') == 'true') {
```

[source](http://www.jquerybyexample.net/2012/06/get-url-parameters-using-jquery.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
//Just use this, no need to do loops:
    var getUrlParameter = function getUrlParameter(sParam) {
        var r = "";

        if (window.locaton.href.substring(window.locaton.href.indexOf(sParam + "="))) {
            r = window.locaton.href.substring(window.locaton.href.indexOf(sParam + "=")(sParam + "=").length + 1);
            // trim if there is other parameter on the list
            if (r.indexOf("&") > 0)
                r = r.substring(0, r.indexOf("&"));
        }
        // please do some simple test, I just wrote it without testing the code
        return r;
    }
```

Comment: It's better to include some context/explanation for code as this makes the answer more useful.

Answer (score 0):

Your code might be assuming that the library purl library, https://github.com/allmarkedup/purl, is loaded but isn't or is inaccessible.

You might try the alternate approach:

```
if(purl().param('ig') == 'true') {
```